# Plot beat waves spectrum

Tags: list-manipulation, fourier-analysis

I have a signal composed of 3 waves oscillating at a high frequency (~10^15 Hz) separated in frequency by 10MHz. I want to simulate the resulting beat wave spectrum. I am expecting a two-peak spectrum, one at 10Mhz and the other one at 20Mhz, due to the beating. Using this code:

```
\[Omega] = 437653.22*10^9;
A = 1;
\[CapitalOmega] = 10*10^6;
\[Beta] = 0.1;
E0[t_] := 
  A*(Exp[I*\[Omega]*t] + \[Beta]*
      Exp[I*(\[CapitalOmega] + \[Omega])*t]/2 - \[Beta]*
      Exp[I*(\[CapitalOmega] - \[Omega])*t]/2);
data = Table[{t, E0[t]}, {t, 0, 1*10^-6, 1*10^-9}];
ListLinePlot[
 Re[data[[All, 2]]],
 AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Small], Red],
 Frame -> True
 ]

Periodogram[
 data[[All, 2]],
 SampleRate -> 50*10^6,
 Frame -> True,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed],
 AspectRatio -> 1/4,
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I managed to get a two-peak spectrum, but the peaks are in the wrong positions. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is code for a similar calculation:

```
(* Choose frequencies closer together to avoid a large data set *)

f1 = 1100; f2 = 1000; f3 = 900;

(* Use a sample rate much greater than Nyquist to avoid aliasing *)

sampleRate = 10 f1;

(* Two-frequency modulation produces the sum and difference *)

TrigReduce[Cos[F1] Cos[F2]]

(* 1/2 (Cos[F1-F2]+Cos[F1+F2]) *)

TrigReduce[Cos[f1] Cos[f2]]

(* 1/2 (Cos[100]+Cos[2100]) *)

(* data generation uses radian frequencies *)

data1 = Table[
   Cos[2 Pi f1 t] Cos[2 Pi f2 t], {t, 0, 1000/f1, 1/sampleRate}];

(* and we see the expected frequencies *)

Periodogram[data1, SampleRate -> sampleRate]
```

[image]

```
(* Three-frequency modulation produces four frequencies *)

TrigReduce[Cos[F1] Cos[F2] Cos[F3]]

(* 1/4 (Cos[F1-F2-F3]+Cos[F1+F2-F3]+Cos[F1-F2+F3]+Cos[F1+F2+F3]) *)

TrigReduce[Cos[f1] Cos[f2] Cos[f3]]

(* 1/4 (Cos[800]+Cos[1000]+Cos[1200]+Cos[3000]) *)

data2 = Table[
   Cos[2 Pi f1 t] Cos[2 Pi f2 t] Cos[2 Pi f3 t], {t, 0, 1000/f1, 
    1/sampleRate}];

Periodogram[data2, SampleRate -> sampleRate]
```

[image]